# Load data from S3 to Redshift using EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I am trying to load Redshift tables from S3 csv files thru EMR pyspark.

My code for Cluster creation is working :

```
import boto3

connection = boto3.client(
    'emr',
    region_name='us ',
    aws_access_key_id='key',
    aws_secret_access_key='secret',
)

cluster_id = connection.run_job_flow(
    Name='Spark_DIF1',
    LogUri="s3:///new-log",
    ReleaseLabel='emr-5.32.0',
    Applications=[
        {
            'Name': 'Spark'
        },
    ],
    Instances={
        'InstanceGroups': [
            {
                'Name': "Master",
                'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',
                'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
                'InstanceType': 'm5.xlarge',
                'InstanceCount': 1,
            },
            {
                'Name': "Slave nodes",
                'Market': 'ON_DEMAND',
                'InstanceRole': 'CORE',
                'InstanceType': 'm5.xlarge',
                'InstanceCount': 2,
            }
        ],
        #'Ec2KeyName': 'BIBA-KEY',
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': False,
        'TerminationProtected': False,
        'Ec2SubnetId': 'subnet-5b673f01',
    },
    Steps=[
        {
            'Name': 'Run Step',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': ['sudo',
                         'spark-submit',
                         '--master', 'yarn',
                         '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                         '--jars','s3a://bucket/jars/RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.51.1078.jar',
                         '--packages', 'com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:2.0.0,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0,com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.4',
                         '--py-files', 's3a://bucket/S3Redshift.py', 's3a://bucket/S3Redshift.py'
                         ]

            }
        }
    ], 
    VisibleToAllUsers=True,
    JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole',
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'tag_name_1',
            'Value': 'tab_value_1',
        },
    ],
)
```

My code to load Redshift:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('app').getOrCreate()
log4jLogger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)

Input_schema1 = StructType([StructField("sepal_length", DecimalType(), True),
                            StructField("sepal_width", DecimalType(), True),
                            StructField("petal_length", DecimalType(), True),
                            StructField("petal_width", DecimalType(), True),
                            StructField("species", StringType(), True)])
lookup_df = spark.read \
              .option("header", "true") \
              .option("inferSchema", "true") \
              .option("schema", Input_schema1) \
              .csv("s3://mltest11/iris.csv")
lookup_df.createOrReplaceTempView("dif_tbl")
final_df= spark.sql("select * from dif_tbl")

final_df.write.format('jdbc').options(
      url='jdbc:redshift://redshiftxxxxxx.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev',
      driver='com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver',
      dbtable='dev.table',
      user='username',
      password='pwd').mode('overwrite').save()

spark.stop()
```

I have created customised role ROLE1 with following policies :
[image]
I am struggling with this issue since two days.

I have attached the above IAM role to my redshift cluster.
Should I have to specify during my EMR cluster creation? If so, how can it be done?

The error I am getting is :

```
21/01/06 11:21:25 INFO Client: Application report for application_xxx_0001 (state: FINISHED)
21/01/06 11:21:25 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User application exited with status 1
     ApplicationMaster host: ip-y-y-y-y.us-west-2.compute.internal
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 38375
     queue: default
     start time: 1609932048473
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://ip-x-x-x-x.us-west-2.compute.internal:20/proxy/application_xxx_0001/
     user: root
21/01/06 11:21:25 ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User application exited with status 1
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_xxx_0001 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1154)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1534)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:937)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
21/01/06 11:21:25 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/01/06 11:21:25 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-0-7c8f-4771-a080-b 
21/01/06 11:21:25 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/tmp/spark-4-3baf-40d1-91e3-a 
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

Any inputs what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: this is not actual log. Please share driver log from `application_xxx_0001`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i find the driver log

Comment: `yarn log application application_xxx_0001` this how you see yarn log